# When I terminate a dying Perl test run using prove -v , why are results not saved to a text file via STDOUT?

Tags: perl, testing, command-line, stdout, win64

I'm driving SeleniumRC and a page hangs, so I hit Ctrl-C to stop testing and address the issue.  If I pass a txt file via the command line like so:

```
prove -v some.t :: data.csv > testresults.txt
```

...I either get nothing or "Terminate batch job (Y/N)? " in the text file.  Note that if I don't pass a file for output via the command line the results scroll by as expected.

Does prove have an option to write to a file via stdout that isn't -v?

This issue persists when I add `$| = 1;` in any of its forms to either `prove.pm` or `some.t`.  Is there something in prove or Test::Harness that is overriding my autoflush setting?

I've also tried this variation:
`prove -v some.t > testresults.txt :: data.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are suffering from buffering. The output is buffered (when not sent to a terminal), and those buffers aren't flushed when you fill the application with Ctrl-C.

If the output comes from a Perl script, try adding `$| = 1;` to it.

Comment: Hmm .. I can't make this work for me, event after `select(STDOUT)`

Comment: Ah. I am a dope. Will try again when I'm back at the office.

Comment: Rats, this still didn't do it.  I've tried adding `$| = 1;` to prove and to the test script itself and get the same result.  I can always just run the .t as a program but I prefer to have a harness around it.

Comment: @kyoob, Sorry, then, don't know how to help :(